# Is there any chemicals that I can add to soy bean wax

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I recently decided to make homemade candles in my spare time since all 6 kids have left the house.

After much research and trial and error and reading many articles, I have found that Soy wax does not release fragrance oil well on its own, and needs an additive/chemical of some sort, but being that I am not a chemistry kinda gal, I don't want to buy certain acids or whatever and risk blowing up my kitchen, or making deadly fumes just because I am not aware of what chemicals can or can't go together.

You can add additives such as Vybar to certain waxes such as paraffin and it will help the color retention, and a few other things, but I am wanting something in the raw form that I can add to the soy wax before it solidifies so when the wick is lit, the fragrance will smell. Soy wax alone has a reputation of not releasing fragrance without using an additive/acid/compound to it. I just don't want to mix something that would be, or could be dangerous.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Then why use this kind of wax in the first place?

Comment: Because they say it is safer for you to breathe then the toxic's that come from paraffin wax. And of course it helps support the farmers. Yet, you can't add a bunch of fragrance, or it will rise to the top and basically drown out the candle, and still won't smell it!

Comment: What about beeswax?

Comment: Beeswax is a quite a bit higher in price, and alters the scent. So pumpkin won't really smell like pumpkin, because of the wax type. However if you use  paraffin, the old fashion wax you will see the black smoke rise on the glass/container up the walls or just black smoke in the air.  I know there are additives I can throw into soy wax just like when ppl use paraffin wax they use vybar and its an additive to promote various things, I just was looking for something like stearic acid to force the soy wax release the fragrance when the wick is lit. Thank you tho!